# First name put as "Mr" in Airticket

Tags: tickets, airlines

My surname is blank in my passport while in my given name i use first name and middle name.
In the airline ticket, agent has put "Mr" as first name and my given name as last name.

Is this correct practice?

Comment: I already had my name wrote in different ways in airline tickets and I never had problems. I have two surnames, and sometimes, they write my First Name and my first Surname together.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Yes**, this is common.  Many airlines render names as `LASTNAME/FIRSTNAMEMR`, which means that without a last name, your name will be shown as just `FIRSTNAMEMR` (or maybe even `/FIRSTNAMEMR`).

See also: [My name has "Mr" appended on airline ticket reservation. Would that cause problems at the airport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30947/my-name-has-mr-appended-on-airline-ticket-reservation-would-that-cause-proble?rq=1)