# No space in given name - Qatar Airways

Tags: tickets, qatar-airways

My given name on passport has a space (example: John Alex). When I booked my ticket on the Qatar airways website, the ticket has been issued as Johnalex *surname*. I am not allowed to modify this. Will this be an issue while boarding? Has anyone experienced a similar situation with Qatar airways?

Comment: That question is NOT a duplicate! It's a completely different question.  Whilst I'm sure there are dups of this question on here somewhere, if you're voting to close as a duplicate please make sure that the question you're linking to is actually the same question!

Comment: This is probably a closer match (albeit not 100% the same, since a given name with a space is slightly different than a first name and a middle name, though the airlines treat it the same): [United Airlines joined my first name and middle name on boarding pass. How to correct this?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/107945/united-airlines-joined-my-first-name-and-middle-name-on-boarding-pass-how-to-co/107946). In any event, it's no problem and something that's extremely common with airline reservation systems.

Comment: Perhaps we should have a canonical question: "What variations are acceptable in the name on an airline ticket?"

Answer (score 8):

No, this is not a problem.

The 'name' field on an airline ticket is very flexible, and spaces within names are treated as "optional" so can be included or not.

The [Amadeus](https://servicehub.amadeus.com/c/portal/view-solution/3893134/en_US/guidelines-on-passenger-name-record-pnr-data) website specifically states :

> 2.6.4.2 When a double name is involved, the space separating the names is optional, i.e. indicate Jesus Raul Gomez Gonzalez as
> GOMEZGONZALEZ/JESUSRAULMR or as GOMEZ GONZALEZ/JESUS RAUL MR

(Amadeus is one of the main airline booking agencies. Others have the same policies around names)

Answer (score 1):

My personal experience with having my name mangled on the ticket is that the worst thing that can happen is that the *automatic* check-in doesn't work and the computer tells you to check in at the counter. Checking in at the counter was never a problem: one look by a *human* as opposed to a computer could immediately tell that the name on the ticket matches the passport. In my case, my first name, middle name, and last name had been smushed together into a single name, and the 'ö' had been deleted completely instead of being transliterated to 'oe'.

In other words, as long as it is possible for a *human* to see that the names on your ticket and your travel documents match, you will likely be able to check in. The worst that can happen is that the check-in at the automated machine does not work, and you have to queue at the counter in order to talk to a human.

As mentioned in [Doc's answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/168504/20425), even that scenario is unlikely, since spaces are ignored when comparing the names.

Answer (score 0):

That depends a lot on the airline and their policy.

Often, you are let go without much hassle, but beware of the [Blue Panorama case](https://en.agcm.it/en/media/press-releases/2019/5/Blue-Panorama-Airlines-fined-one-million-euro) in 2019.

The airline was fined 1M euros for having refused to board, *unless they paid a hefty penalty*, passengers whose name on ID/passport didn't **exactly** match the name displayed on ticket. It was meant as an additional hassle/threat to the passenger who had to choose in a very limited time (and without option to call/connect for an advisory), without substantial legal/security grounds.

(emphasis mine)

> PRESS RELEASE
>
> The Italian Competition Authority has closed the investigation against Blue Panorama Airlines S.p.A., finding the company liable for an unfair commercial practice in breach of Articles 24 and 25 of Italian Legislative Decree n. 206/2005 (Consumer Code).
>
> In particular, the conduct concerned the application of a penalty to consumers - initially consisting in payment for a new ticket to be able to use the service already purchased and, subsequently, a fee of 50 euros per route - **in cases of incorrect registration of the passenger’s name at the time of booking, specifically for cases of omission of any middle names or surname or in the case of alteration/lack of some letters**.
>
> The request for the aforesaid penalty, which occurred directly at the airport, with the flight imminently leaving and under penalty of not being allowed to board, *proved to be substantially independent from the security needs of air travel*. Moreover, *the airline did not provide any advance information regarding the consequences of incomplete registration of the name when booking*; additionally, in some cases, this discrepancy was due to the characteristics of the airline’s online purchase system - with regard to the limited space available for inserting all names/surnames of passengers - or to the misalignment between operating interfaces with the websites of certain sale intermediaries.
>
> In assessing the gravity of the infringement in order to impose a penalty of 1 million euros, the Authority took into account the widespread nature of the conduct which has affected a very large number of consumers and the evidence acquired from investigations which showed the clear objective of increasing business revenue via this policy.
>
> During the proceedings, the Authority was supported by the Special Antitrust Unit of the Italian Finance Police.
>
> Rome, May 31, 2019