# United Flights Cannot Be Added to CheckMyTrips

Tags: air-travel, bookings

I just started using the CheckMyTrip app to manage my flights. I have been unable to add any United-booked flights on the app. I get this message on CheckMyTrip:

"Sorry, your profile information doesn't match the booking. Please head to Settings/My Profile and make sure your first and last names are the same as the ones used to make the reservation."

I assume this is because United concatenates first and middle names in its reservation data (see [United Airlines joined my first name and middle name on boarding pass. How to correct this?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/107945/united-airlines-joined-my-first-name-and-middle-name-on-boarding-pass-how-to-co)), so the first name is "FIRSTMIDDLE" instead of "FIRST". This would also be a problem for people with hyphenated last names, because United's system strips any punctuation from the name.

Has anyone else experienced this? Is there any way to make this work?

Answer (score 6):

CheckMyTrip is a service run by Amadeus, who are one of the three main airline booking systems (Sabre and Travelport being the other two).

Presumably you are trying to use their feature of adding a booking by entering the confirmation code for that trip - this feature only works for confirmation codes that exist within the Amadeus system.

United Airlines does not use Amadeus, but instead use it's own booking system called SHARES. As a result, United Airlines confirmation codes will not work in CheckMyTrip.

There is one partial exception to this - if you trip was booked via a travel agency, and that travel agency itself uses Amadeus, then your booking will have both an Amadeus confirmation code and a SHARES confirmation code.  In this case, you will be able to use the Amadeus confirmation code (but NOT the SHARES one!) in CheckMyTrip to view your reservation.

CheckMyTrip also offers two other ways to add trip details - either by forwarding them to plans@checkmytrip.com, or entering the details manually.  Both of these options will work fine for trips booked with United Airlines.

Comment: I think I tried to add United trips manually and was unable to because of the name mismatch. (I deleted a trip and tried to add it back manually but get just a black screen when I press "Add a trip".) However, the email approach did work. Thanks for the explanation.